# C#8 nullable checks

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a class with a nullable type, like this:

```
#nullable enable
class Foo {
    public SomeType? Name { get; }
}
#nullable restore
```

After checking for null, I put the instance in a list and do some other stuff with it. For a statical analyzer it gets really difficult to know, that *Name* is not null. Currently, the compiler complains all the time, which is annoying, and I don't really want to use the `!` operator, to force him to be quiet.
Somehow I want to mark the instance as "null-checked".

One option is to create a wrapper of *Foo* having `public SomeType Name { get; }`. This looks like a lot of work though.

Are there other options? Are there any future plans which tackle those situations?

Comment: `a lot of work though.` why? What's the actual problem? What's the situation you refer to?

Comment: The point is to *not* have nulls in the code unless explicitly allowed and handled. `SomeType?` should be the exception, not the rule

Comment: "After checking for null [...]", is the object validated right after creation, or are there processes that rightfully need to treat the contents as possibly null until then?

Comment: The issue is that you logically have two versions of `Foo`, one for which `Name` could be null, and one where it cannot be null. This implies that you should be using two different types (as per your wrapper suggestion).

Comment: @Felk: I let myself believe I needed the null type. Since at a first step it is possible to have it null. But I probably have to rethink that. All the later steps are after the validation. Also, some data gets added as the algorithm progresses. But in fact, it's not really a nullable type, just a lazy value..

Comment: I like to think of the `!` operators as a "I know better than you operator" rather than a "be quiet operator". There is a [`MemberNotNullWhenAttribute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.membernotnullwhenattribute?view=net-5.0) in .NET 5.0 that could help… However, the compiler would still not know that all the elements you add to the list were validated already. A different type is the right option. You could, for example, have a `FooDescriptor` struct that allows nulls, and a `Foo` class that does not. Or `Foo` class and `ValidatedFoo` class, etc.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yes, you are right. See the comment above. I have multiple steps, where, at first, the value can be null. After filtering and data aggregation, I don't want the nullable type anymore. So I should somehow get rid of the nullable type.

Comment: Explain what you want to do *in the question itself*.

Comment: @Theraot: Thx for your input. ```MemberNotNull*``` looks interesting..